# django: How to order the queryset on a field in ManyToManyField (through) related models

Tags: python, sql, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have these models

```
class Region (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 255, blank = False)

class Album(TimeStampAwareModel):
    title = models.CharField (max_length = 255, blank = False) 
    digital_release_date = models.ManyToManyField( Region, through="AlbumRegionReleaseDate", related_name="release_date_albums")
    published = models.BooleanField (default = False)
    .
    .

class AlbumRegionReleaseDate(models.Model):
   album = models.ForeignKey (Album)
   region = models.ForeignKey (Region)
   digital_release_date = models.DateField () 
   class Meta:
    ordering = ('-digital_release_date')
```

Suppose i have three regions i:e Europe, South Asia and North Asia

Now i want to get all "published" albums order by "digital_release_date" in Europe region?

Can anyone please tell me how to do this by SQL query?

Thanks :)

Comment: Having spaces before and after parentheses in method/function calls and class definitions is generally not done in python. It's legal, but very much non-standard. (link to PEP...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Sorry, my mistake! Now this should work. I tried it at home...

```
Album.objects.filter(
    published=True,
    albumregionreleasedate__region__name='Europe'
).order_by(
    'albumregionreleasedate__digital_release_date'
)
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) is some help to future doubts

Hope it works now!

Comment: You can't do this `digital_release_date__digital_release_date` it throws `FieldError` because `digital_release_date` in model `Album` pointing to model `Region`.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake... Try it now. It should work! Or try @DiegoNavarro option, but with the field name i recommend (the name you put to the related_name parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you are using Django's ORM, you probably don't want to do it 'by SQL query'.

If you always want to order them (by default) that way, I would think the best solution would be to put an ordering attribute on your through model's Meta inner class:

```
class AlbumRegionReleaseDate(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    digital_release_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('region', 'digital_release_date')
```

If you want just one query that does that, without using the default ordering, ... I'll have to think some more.

Comment: thanks to reply but i want one query to do this, because i want region to be input to that query

Comment: i want something like this `Album.objects.raw('SELECT store_album.*, t2.digital_release_date FROM store_album , (SELECT * FROM  store_albumregionreleasedate t1 WHERE t1.region_id=%s) AS t2  WHERE store_album.id = t2.album_id ORDER BY t2.digital_release_date', [r1.id])` here store is my app name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like:

```
Region.objects.get(name='Europe').album_set.filter(published=True).order_by('digital_release_date')
```

Comment: you cant get albums from region, there is no link between each others **AttributeError: 'Region' object has no attribute 'album_set'**

Comment: Yes, you can. Maybe with a different name. Try to dir(region_object) and see what you have. You will find something like <model>_set. You can go through relations in both ways (direct and inverse).

Comment: `album_set` won't work. If he hadn't rename the relations, what could have work is `albumregionreleasedate_set`. But if you look at the definition of that field, you will see a related_name parameter. That's the name to use from the related objects. So in your example will be `Region.objects.get(name='Europe').release_date_albums.filter(published=True).order_by('digital_release_date')
`

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning this method works on an object instance, not a QuerySet. The QuerySet will also throw an **AttributeError**.